# Word-related answer that I don't have the privelege to comment on

Tags: microsoft-word

I hoped to learn something useful new when I went to this post 
[Microsoft Wildcards](https://superuser.com/questions/742052/microsoft-word-wildcards?rq=1)

...but when I tried the accepted answer, it could not find the **The** **in the middle of the sentence**, or ***after the open space*** *(never mind *replace* anything)*

[image: find and replace with wildcard trial screenshot]

Did I misunderstand something, or is it for a specific Word version?

Comment: @Madball73 Please will you help me out on this one?

Comment: Madball73 last visited the site 2 yrs ago.  In general, though, the @ addressing only works for users who have already participated on that specific post.

Comment: This regex was supposed to find "the", not "The". First step described by the person who asked the question was to change all "The" to "the" and proceed from there to change relevant "the" to "The".

Comment: @endrju - Thanks, I see what you mean - but it *also* did NOT find....Why???

Comment: This regex is suspicious. I think curly braces inside square braces lose special meaning. For "The" inside a sentence (e.g. not after a dot and a group of spaces) use ([!.] @)(The)

Comment: One space is missing in brackets: ([!. ] @)(The)

Answer (score 0):

Click the "More" button on the search window, and check the box "Use Wildcards".

[image]

Once you have that checked the advanced regex features shown in your linked question will function.

Comment: Thank you, it made sense when i read it, but again, Word does not find the required incidences.... :-(